# Grid is capacitive in the evening

Tags: ac, solar-cell, power-engineering, capacitive, storage

what does this term mean? "the grid in the evening is capacitive"? 
I work at a company and we are working on integrating a battery storage system on a utility scale for peak shaving of solar. When we asked a consultant, the reply was: "it does not matter because the grid is capacitive"

Any clue on where to start looking even?

Comment: okay, what does dumping current into the grid mean? excuse my weak knoweldge, but isn't a increase in demand actually require power to be supplied from a source?

Comment: Next time, why not simply ask the consultant to explain what he means when he says that. You can dump more electricity in the grid, the voltage will increase only slightly and every device on the grid will consume 0.0001% more power to eat up all the power you just dumped. The grid does not have a constant voltage, it varies and within limits that is OK. And in the evening many lights are on, they will all just burn 0.0001% brighter.

Comment: Sounds to me like he is implying that less inductive loads operate during the evening hours, making it net "capacitive." The last photo [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor) shows capacitors installed in an electrical substation to offset the inherent inductive loads present.

Answer (score 5):

The grid is generally inductive, not capacitive.  This means the current lags the voltage a bit.

The grid is specified as a voltage source.  The power producers set the voltage, then the loads draw whatever current they draw.  Ideally this current is instantaneously proportional to the voltage.  A resistor has this characteristic.  However, many loads on the grid are motors, which have a inductive component.  Some loads are capacitive, but generally the inductive loads outweigh the capacitive ones, and the grid as a whole has a inductive load on it.

You don't say where this is, but perhaps in your local area once whatever industry you have shuts down for the day, the overall grid load becomes capacitive.

If you are going to dump power onto the grid, your equipment has to be able to source current that is somewhat out of phase with the voltage.  Again, generally the current lags the voltage, but for robustness you should be able to tolerate a significant power factor either way.

Comment: I was under the impression that the grid itself, in the absence of any loads, is primarily capacitive. In other words, the capacitance of the wires to the environment outweighs their self-inductance. A lot of industrial loads are inductive (large motors that are not fully loaded), so "during the day" when more of them are turned on, the grid is inductive overall, but "at night", when most of the loads are resistive loads such as lighting and heating, the capacitance dominates.

Comment: @Dave: I heard that the grid is usually inductive all the time anyway, but I don't remember where I heard that from, and it probably varies by location.

Comment: @DaveTweed yes this makes sense. But what does it have to do with loads? what I mean is, the consultant's answer to the fact that at night there is a big consumption of energy, that "well, the grid is capacitive". Does this imply that the consumption is less? does this mean that we do not need a battery system for example to provide power for these loads? how is the grid being inductive or capacitive affect the amount of energy required to run stuff?

Comment: @Moha: Do you understand what power factor is, and the difference between real and reactive power?

Comment: @OlinLathrop yes i do

Answer (score 1):

This is a new answer to an old question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHXD9A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we simplify the grid feeder transmission lines with some mH/km and nF/km for each line, what is the difference between differential impedance and common mode impedance?

Imagine it as a 3 phase line since this is not included in the schematic tool but it doesn't matter in this hand-waving argument. The capacitance line to line will be different than line to earth ground plane. The differential inductance will add for 2 lines but cancel for common mode inductance. To further match lines grids swap 2 of 3 different lines every kilometer to enhance the nulling of common mode inductance. Yet the common mode capacitance adds to each line if you have a 3 phase coil with a neutral connection.

The inductance is between the lines that flow current in a loop and at a distance the inductance cancels.

**Therefore the grid is capacitive!** ( but depends on wire diameter and height above ground and also %RH or rain density.  I would expect Zcm(f) to reduce at least 25 to 50% from dry to RH=50%. [This is a research article](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Capacitance-versus-relative-humidity-relationship-for-the-Al-VOPcPhO-Au-capacitive-sensor_fig6_234055193) which agrees with C almost 1.5 x dry air at RH=50% and exponentially increases with saturated air as Dk = 80 is relatively constant for water, but raindrops repel each other with like charges leaking a small drier air gap between.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even when unloaded, the transmission and distribution lines are taking charging currents. This is due to the capacitance between the phases, and between the phases and ground.

The lines also have a series inductance, but the inductance is not "consuming" much of the reactive power produced by the capacitances, when unloaded or weakly loaded, and the total reactive power of the grid is capacitive.

If the load current increases, the series inductance of the line start to consume more and more reactive power. Also the load can be inductive, and this reactive power must be produced somewhere too. If the line's capacitances cannot produce all the reactive power needed by the load and the line itself, the grid sum up as inductive.

So to answer the question. The grid is probably capacitive when the load currents are low, because of the line capacitances are dominating.