# How does line capacitance of overhead naked lines change with rain or snow?

Tags: capacitance, network, line, overhead-lines

Does line capacitance change with rain or snow? If yes, does it a lot (or is there a study that quantifies the change)? I ask it because I am studying the tuning of a Petersen coil, and I want to know if the capacitance may change with bad weather conditions and so if the Petersen coil must be tuned to the line capacitance change if present

Comment: Have you searched on IEEE Xplore?

Comment: Are you asking about overhead power lines, like those on poles?

Comment: @relayman357 Hi! Yes, I did but I didn't find anything related to my doubt unfortunately :(

Comment: @SteveSh yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the capacitance will change.  Capacitance between a pair of wires is proportional to the relative permittivity of the insulating material - air in this case.  Rain or snow will affect that permittivity, and so affect the capacitance.  How much depends on how much rain or snow is occurring.

The permittivity of pure water is approximately 80 times higher than that of air.  I guess you would have to take a weighted or density average of the two permittivities to arrive at a new permittivity, and plug that into the equation (readily available) for the capacitance between a pair of wires.

Comment: Visiting an Omega station (navigation system operating at 10kHz to 14kHz) back in the 1970s, they had a giant tuning room which would compensate for cloud cover. The antenna was strung between two mountain ridges and was often in the clouds.

Comment: Now that's a tank circuit @qrk

Comment: I used a whip antenna on a spring to thwart playful polar bears in the Beaufort sea to pick up to Navy VLF stations around the same time. But the weather station ended up in Siberia.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Capacitance-versus-relative-humidity-relationship-for-the-Al-VOPcPhO-Au-capacitive-sensor_fig6_234055193

I do not have any precise measurements for the grid or feeders or a line well above the earth, but the above research has measured it.

I expect a "line field effect" to have an inverse square law to capacitance with distance and an inverse square law to %RH with a limiting factor being the relative permeability of water = 80 never achieved, otherwise we couldn't breathe.
[image]

Also, see a related question here:
[Grid is capacitive in the evening](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214661/grid-is-capacitive-in-the-evening/617472#617472)